# How to remove margin from zurb foundation text-field

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation's text field have a `1em` bottom margin that I want to remove.

I couldn't find custom scss in zurb [foundation documents.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html)

I'm overwriting the stylesheet by using `!important` option.
But if possible I don't want to use it.

Is there better way to remove the margin from foundation form text field?
I'm using foundation in a rails project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the styles without using !important option.

If there are multiple contradictory CSS file then whichever gets called LAST will override the previous one.

For example if you add below styles in your CSS file and include it after docs.css then it gets highest priority.

Have a look at the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwgj2/)

```
input[type="text"]{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks web2008, I was trying only with class name, that was the reason  the css didn't have effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the SCSS method you want to change the value for $form-spacing;

[Forms | Foundation for Sites 6 docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/forms.html)

$form-spacing: rem-calc(16);